# Why does Heroku require Resque 1.22.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

AFAIK resque 1.22.0 is pretty old. Resque-scheduler has to be downgraded from 4.3.0 to 2.2.0 just to support is. What reason is there that Heroku requires Resque at 1.22.0?

Comment: This will answer your question https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque#resque-on-heroku

Comment: So, if it says, "starting 1.22" it maintains the UNIX standard, doesn't that mean versions > 1.22.0 should work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question. It appears @Pavan was right. I'm running resque 1.26.0 right now with no problems. Perhaps I should update the link on Heroku to >= 1.22.0 ..